# How to define a class and module for a view created programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, uiview, subview

Let's say I create a view like this:

```
let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
self.view.addSubview(myView)
```

How can I give that view a custom `class` and `module` like I would in IB?

I am either searching for the wrong thing, or no one has asked this question. I also haven't tried anything because I can't figure out where to even start.

**Update:**

This is what I mean by adding a `class` and `module` like you would in IB:

[image]

Comment: The only thing that you need to do is to make another target (a cocoa touch framework in your case) and make the class a member of that target (and of course link the framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply instantiate it instead of `UIView`.

Assuming this is your custom view:

```
class MyCustomView: UIView {
    //...
}
```

Here is how to instantiate it:

```
let myView = MyCustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
self.view.addSubview(myView)
```

The module is the module your source file of `class MyCustomView: UIView...` is member of. When developing an iOS application (not a framework or other target types) this is your app. You can choose the "Target Membership" in Xcodes Inspector when selecting a source file:

[image]

Comment: Okay, but what about the module?

Comment: Updated answer.